# Washer in front or behind cabinet panel mounted with lag screws?

Tags: screws

I'm going to be mounting a network cabinet on some studs. I was advised to use lag screws. (Not really sure what these are but I assume they are for heavy things being secured to studs).

Should I be putting washers behind the mount in front of the wall, or under the top of the head of the screw but still on the front of the mount itself (so it'd be Top Of Screw|Washer|Mounting Bracket Metal|Wall)?

Comment: Make  sure to pre-drill your hole to a twitch smaller than the minor diameter of the lag screw threads, or you have a chance of hearing a mighty CRAKK! As you tighten.  Also don't go in more than 1-5/8" past the wall surface or you have a chance to nick electrical cables or pipes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Washers are almost always to 1) spread the load of the screw head to a larger area, and 2) to prevent damage to the face of the component being fastened. They can also be used as spacers, but I don't see a need for that here.

In your case, the washers go under the screw head and over the cabinet mount.